# WiX IIS Authentication mode on subdirectories

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, wix

I'm trying to install a ASP.NET MVC web application with wix. So far so good.
Unfortunately I came up with a pretty annoying issue I don't know how to implement.

Imagine the following WebSite structure:

- Default Web Site (Windows authentication)

  - MyApplication  (Windows authentication)

    - WebServices (Anoynmous authentication)

As you can see the whole website can only be accessed with valid NT credentials.
But I need to set anonymous authentication on the WebServices directory.
How can I accomplish this with wix?

```
<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLDIR_WEB">
    <!-- Configuring app pool -->
    <Component Id="Cmp_AppPool" Guid="27CE75BF-1118-4E15-9CD5-6FA973A20B45" KeyPath="yes">
    <util:User Id="AppPoolUser" Domain="[APPPOOL_IDENTITYDOMAIN]" Name="[APPPOOL_IDENTITY]" Password="[APPPOOL_IDENTITYPWD]" CreateUser="no" />
            <iis:WebAppPool Id="CustomAppPool" ManagedPipelineMode="[APPPOOL_PIPELINEMODE]" ManagedRuntimeVersion="[APPPOOL_ManagedRuntimeVersion]" Name="[APPPOOL_NAME]" Identity="other" User="AppPoolUser" />
        </Component>

        <!-- Create new WebApplication -->
        <Component Id="Cmp_CreateApplication" Guid="65591914-46A9-4CB7-BF2E-9F30F4DEE3EC" KeyPath="yes">
            <Condition><![CDATA[Installed OR WEBAPP_NAME <> ""]]></Condition>
            <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="MyWebVirtualDir" Alias="[WEBAPP_NAME]" Directory="INSTALLDIR_WEB" WebSite="DefaultWebSite">
                <iis:WebDirProperties Id="MyWebVirtDirProperties" AnonymousAccess="no" BasicAuthentication="no" WindowsAuthentication="yes" />
                <iis:WebApplication Id="MyWebWebApplication" Name="[WEBAPP_NAME]" WebAppPool="CustomAppPool" />
            </iis:WebVirtualDir>
        </Component>
        <!-- Install directly in the IIS ROOT -->
        <Component Id="Cmp_SetPermissions">
            <iis:WebDir Path="WebServices" DirProperties="EnableAnonymousAuth" WebSite="DefaultWebSite" Id="ServiceDir" />
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>

<iis:WebDirProperties Id="EnableAnonymousAuth" Read="yes" Write="yes" Script="yes" Execute="yes" AnonymousAccess="yes" Index="no" LogVisits="no" />
```

The above code successfully creates the webapplication but does not set anonymous access on the WebServices directory.

Any ideas?

Regards
Lukas

Comment: "INSTSALLED" - misprint and invalid char register. Should be "Installed".

In your case even "Not Installed"?

Comment: tnx, you're right but this did not solve my main issue

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the condition. You want the component to be installed only if the product installed or WEBAPP_NAME is not empty?

Answer (score 1):

There is WebDirProperties element for WebDir.
You can set AnonymousAccess="yes" there.

Also you should also provide the user account using the AnonymousUser attribute, and determine what setting to use for the IIsControlledPassword attribute.

Comment: Yes, there is but is seems not to work! I reference it with the DirProperties EnableAnonymousAuth!! I editet the example above

Comment: WiX help contains: Sets the Enable Anonymous Access checkbox, which maps anonymous users to a Windows user account. When setting this to 'yes' you should also provide the user account using the AnonymousUser attribute, and determine what setting to use for the IIsControlledPassword attribute.

Comment: Are you able to provide some example markup? I really don't want to provide any anonymous credentials! It should use the built in default user!!